# fast index format for 'constant database'

Tags: c, database, linux, algorithm

I am doing c programming on linux and met a problem that needs extremely fast look-up speed.

If a table, like a normal MySQL table, looks like the following:

```
ID   name   age   sex  score_a   score_b  score_c  date
```

and it is **constant**, which means once this table was created and no updates were allowed. It only serves for reading. Since it was constant so I guess there must be a better index format for faster looking up by conditions (like age, scores, etc), rather than 'B tree index' implemented in most databases for index.

Comment: Looks hash will be the only way.

Comment: @PasteBT hash cannot support filtering, I guess it is not probably for me

Comment: I need more info.  What do you mean by "fast," and "not fast enough?" what kinds of queries are you running, and how complex are your filters?  Are you running the same queries over and over, or are they highly variable?

Comment: Also how many rows are in this table?

Comment: If you want to optimize for range look up, try duplicating the table with each sorted by different keys. . No, there are no general solution. You need different method for different filter.

Comment: @Ben Burns about 10M - 300M rows

Comment: You should first define the form of queries on this table. If you are only looking by some given ID it is one thing, if you want complex expressions involving relations and arithmetic between several fields it is another thing. If you want set operations or joins it is yet another thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to be doing range-based searching ('age between 10 and 12, 13 and 15, etc', 'score a between 40 and 60, 61 and 70, etc') or single value searching ('name is Quentin Smith') or both?  For single value searching, hash is appropriate and fast; for range-based searching in particular, B-tree and its variants tend to be best.

You're looking at somewhere in the region of 50 bytes per row for the original data, so you'd be dealing with 1/2 GB to 15 GB of data.  If it is at the upper end of that range, you are going to need a big machine just to keep the plain data in memory, let alone indexes on it.  At the lower-end of the range, it is well within bounds of plausibility.  Your indexes are likely to take up a little more space than the raw data (maybe 50% more), assuming you index each of the columns.  The name index will be the biggest, of course.  The ID column might not need an index if you can use it as an index into the array of records, but there's probably gaps in the data so it is likely best to index it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your question.  In short, if the data is constant I'd assume the queries you need to run against it are fairly constant as well?

Most modern RDBMS' support some form of query caching.  If yours does not, you can cache the result of your queries in something like memcached.  Generating the cache will be slow, but if cache lookups are kept local, it will be very fast in comparison to index lookups - typically O(1).

Comment: 'fast' means faster than most database index (eg MySQL) with query cache off

Comment: I need something more concrete than that.  What is your acceptance criteria?  What is the bigger problem which the present "slowness" is causing?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous file-based constant databases that might be considered as well.
Search for 'constant database' in stackoverflow or Google or Bing and you'll find some like:

mcdb
https://github.com/gstrauss/mcdb/   (for which I am the author)

Tokyo Cabinet
http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/

hamsterdb
http://www.hamsterdb.com

... and there are others.